# Load different tooltip content for each link

Tags: jquery, ajax, tooltip, simpletip

I use this tooltip script on my site: http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/

The problem is that I have several links in the same div class and I want to load different content in tooltip when the mouse is over different links. This is the code I use to load tooltip:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Create your tooltips 
var api = $(".ttip a").simpletip().simpletip(); 
api.load('include.php'); 
});
```

It would be great if I could send some post parameters in include.php file, based on the link that is actually hovered.

```
<div class="ttip">
<a userid="1" href="#" >user1</a><br />
<a userid="2" href="#">user2</a>
</div>
```

I need to catch the user id in include.php file in order to return appropriate information.

Now the tooltip works only for the first link. For the second one some default text is shown instead when I hover it!

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to assign the tooltips to each element separate and pass the userid using the 2nd parameter of load():

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".ttip a")
  .each(
  function(i)
  { 
    var api=$(this).simpletip().simpletip(); 
    api.load('include.php',{userid:$(this).attr('userid')}); 
  })
});
```